# How to choose a sample from the data points that represent normal distribution?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normal-distribution

I have a data frame in which the target value is not in normal distribution. I want to choose only a sample of the data that represent a normal distribution of this target. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It might not be possible to always cherry pick a normally distributed subset.
Take for example, if your target values are a constant function.

If we know the current distribution, we might still figure out a way to do this.

Without knowing apiori the nature of current distribution, I can only think of one way but is brutally computationally intensive :

- generate subsets of the your list of values
- for each subset run the test to verify if it's normally distributed
- return any one of these subsets where it satisfies your criteria

To run normality test on `array A`: `scipy.stats.normaltest(A)`

Consult the [scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.normaltest.html) for more context

Comment: thank you for your comment, how can I verify if it's normally distrubuted?

Answer (score 0):

With the given information, this is a sampling question. I am not sure whether this is an acceptable practise to choose a targeted sample. Instead, choose samples randomly and make sure they follow normal distribution. If the sample is not normally distributed, try normalizing your target value using transformation procedures. For example, a square root transformation might make your target value normal. More information on the problem will help address this comprehensively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is my data has negative values I can not do square root transformation

Comment: Square root transformation is one method. There are several methods to deal with negative values. Usually a bias is added (eg., a constant value of 1) to the whole sample to address the negative value and continue with other transformations. There are several methods for normality test such as Kolmogorov-Smirnov (K-S) normality test and Shapiro-Wilk’s test. Here is a tutorial on that. http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/normality-test-in-r . A gentle introduction to transformation is here https://towardsdatascience.com/types-of-transformations-for-better-normal-distribution-61c22668d3b9